# Accuracy of a dac - INL rating how that relates to deviation in mV's

Tags: dac

In the datasheets of a dac they talk about the INL error. As I understand this is to do with how much the output of the dac deviates from the output of an ideal DAC. So I was wondering how does that translate to how much the voltage will deviate in mV's? I'm using a MCP4922. The datasheet say it can be as high as +/- 12LSB.

Answer (score 2):

\$ V_{INL}=\frac{INL}{2^n}*V_{fullscale} \$ will get you what you want.  Where N = number of bits.

INL is the deviation from an ideal straight line.